# UI for representing a function of two variables

Tags: user-interface, function

I'm trying to build a web interface representing a 2 dimensional function.

f1(x,y) = z
f2(z,x) = y
f3(z,y) = x

e.g. if f1: 10x / y=z

I'm envisioning three sliders which react to each other.

Ascii interpretation :)

```
x 0--3---------9  (pretend this is a slider)
y 0-----5------9
z 0--------6---9  f(3,5) -> 6
```

Sliding the z axis down, causes either/or/both of x and y to react so as to abide by the function.

I understand a way to implement this, but I'm wondering if something already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with them myself, but the jQuery sliders seem quite appropriate for this case: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

but I'm not sure the best way to represent multiple solution sets...for instance, in your 10x/y=z, what would you want to happen if x were moved to 2? Would you want y to go to 4 and z to 5? or vice versa? Or does your particular function not have that situation?

Comment: implicitly, either y or z would have to respond. Making clear which one moves is part of what makes it difficult. My initial thought was to be able to interactively "lock one", slide one, and let the third respond. I was just hoping that something already existed to see if it would "feel"natural.

Comment: then what about a checkbox per slider for 'hold constant'

Comment: from op: I understand a way to implement this, but I'm wondering if something already exists.